# Known methods to detect coordinate singularities?

Tags: differential-geometry, riemannian-geometry

**MOTIVATION**

In Riemannian geometry, when one writes the metric tensor in a particular coordinate system, certain 'fake' singularities might appear that have little to do with the geometry near them.

For instance, on the sphere $S^2$, one has (with appropriate labelling)

$$ds^2 = d\phi^2 + \sin^2(\phi)d\theta^2$$

and so it looks as though the spherical metric is singular at $\phi = 0$ or $\phi = \pi/2$, but we know it is actually not. However, the only reason we know this is because we have other descriptions of this metric that are evidently not singular anywhere.

**SETUP**

Suppose you have a smooth manifold (let's say three-dimensional) $M$ and you are given a 
local description of a metric

$$ds^2 = g_{ij}dx^idx^j$$

on a coordinate patch $U \subseteq M$. If you want, you can assume this $U$ is dense in $M$, like in the sphere. Suppose that the metric looks singular near the points in $M\backslash{}U$.

Here, I mean the same type of singularity as in the sphere, that is, some crucial terms $g_{ij}$ vanish when you go away from $U$, so that the matrix $[g_{ij}]$ would have zero determinant.

**Question**: What are the known methods for not just detecting, but actually **proving** that the metric is **not** singular and therefore can be extended to the whole $M$?

Comment: The singularity appearing in your description comes from the coordinate system. You can avoid this by using coordinate systems that don't themselves have singularities.

Comment: @QiaochuYuan I think this just changes the question into: how does one go about finding singularity-free coordinate systems?

Answer (score 7):

I think there are two slightly different questions here. The first question is the one you specifically asked: If we are given the manifold $M$ and a metric defined on a dense coordinate chart $U\subseteq M$, what is a sufficient condition for the metric to have a smooth extension to all of $M$?  This is basically pretty easy to answer: just find, for each point in $p\in M\smallsetminus U$, a smooth chart on a neighborhood $V$ of $p$, and transform the metric into the new coordinates on $V\cap U$.  If the transformed metric extends smoothly to $V$, then $p$ was just a coordinate singularity. If $M$ is compact, you can do this with finitely many charts, and often finitely many will do in the noncompact case as well.

The more subtle question arises when $M$ is not known in advance. In this case, we have a smooth metric on an open manifold $U$, and we want to know whether there is *some* smooth manifold $M$ properly containing $U$ and a smooth metric on $M$ that extends the given metric on $U$.  (When this is the case, the given metric on $U$ is said to be *extendible*.) This is a much more difficult question to answer.  There are some obvious necessary conditions for a metric to be extendible: for example, the metric must be geodesically incomplete, and all of the sectional curvatures have to remain bounded as you approach the boundary of $U$.  But I would be surprised if there are any simple sufficient conditions.

To see how strange things can get, let $U$ be the universal cover of $S^2$ with the north and south poles removed, with the metric obtained by pulling back the standard round metric via the projection $U\to S^2$.  (You can visualize this as an "infinite-sheeted orange peel.") Then $U$ is diffeomorphic $\mathbb R^2$, and the pullback metric is incomplete and has constant sectional curvature, but it's not extendible.

Answer (score 2):

Qiaochu's comment misses the point: Some metrics have true singularities that cannot be removed by a change of coordinates.

I don't know about general metric spaces, but in good-old 4-D space-time,  a  sufficient condition for a true singularity to exist at point $P$ is that the limit as one approaches the singularity of the trace of the Ricci tensor goes to infinity  as one approaches $P$.

this is a fairly powerful test, but I don't remember if this is also a necessary condition; I think it is given sufficient differentiability of the metric.

It turns out that it is not sufficient (although for the Schwartzchild solution this scalar is $\frac{48G^2 M^2}{c^4r^6}$ so it does, contrary to one of the comments, tell you that the singularity at $r=0$ is true.) For metrics that are at least semi-Reimannian, the necessary and sufficient condition for non-singularity is that in the Ricci Decomposition of the curvature, all three of the following are non-singular:  The scalar curvature (my original criterion); the semi-traceless part of the curvature tensor, and the fully traceless Weyl tensor. This applies in any number of dimensions above 2. I think the charged Kerr-Newman solution might pass the scalar curvature condition but fail the semi-traceless part condition at the ring of singularities.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, Mark. What I would like to know is some criterion that goes in the other way, namely, if (X) is met, then the singularity does not exist, for sure. I guess this would be the "necessary" part of the condition you gave.

Comment: I don't think your condition could be made necessary, otherwise we would have a problem with Schwarzschild spacetime, because this one is Ricci-flat, the limit you consider would be null. But it does have the benefit of being intuitively the same condition as divergent density of energy, so you do have a point. Unfortunately it is very restricted to general relativity.

Comment: Do you have a reference for the necessary/sufficient claim?